# How to show one element at a time in a quiz

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple quiz that asks user few multiple choice questions about what kind of car they should buy.

How do I go about showing only one question at a time? Like adding a 'next' and 'previous' button. I'm still a beginner at Javascript and I can't find the answer to this.

[Here is my code on codepen](https://codepen.io/Eyad-Alshafi/pen/bWwOrG)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>What kind of car should I buy?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>What kind of car should I buy?</h1>
    <p id="suggestion"></p>

  <form id="form" action="">
    <p>What size do you need?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="compact">Compact<br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="mid">Midsize<br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="small">Small SUV<br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="med">Medium SUV<br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="big">Big SUV

    <p>What kind of driving will you be doing?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="drive" value="city">City/suburb driving<br>
    <input type="radio" name="drive" value="mountain">Mountain driving

    <p>Which would you rather have?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="mpg" value="gas">Good gas milage<br>
    <input type="radio" name="mpg" value="performance">Performance

    <p>How much do luxury features matter to you?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="money" value="save">I'd rather save money and have less luxury features<br>
    <input type="radio" name="money" value="luxury">I'd rather spend a little more and have luxury features.

    <p><input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></p>
    </form> 

  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my Javascript

```
const types = {
  size: {
    compact: 'compact',
    mid: 'mid',
    small: 'small',
    med: 'med',
    big: 'big'
  },
  drive: {
    city: 'city',
    mountain: 'mountain'
  },
  mpg: {
    gas: 'gas',
    performance: 'performance'
  },
  money: {
    save: 'save',
    luxury: 'luxury'
  }
};

const cars = [
  {
    car: 'Prius',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.compact,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW i-3',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.compact,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Civic SI',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.compact,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW 328',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.compact,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Mini Cooper All4',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.compact,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW 328 XI',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.compact,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW XI',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.compact,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Subaru Impreza',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.compact,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },

  {
    car: 'Accord Hybrid',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.mid,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW 528',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.mid,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'VW CC',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.mid,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Subaru Legacy',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.mid,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW 528 XI',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.mid,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Dodge Charger AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.mid,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Audi A4 Quattro',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.mid,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },

  {
    car: 'Rav4 Hybrid',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.small,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Buick Encore',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.small,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Mazda CX-5',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.small,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW X3',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.smal,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Honda CR-V AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.small,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Buick Encore AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.small,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Mazda CX-5 AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.small,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW X3 AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.small,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },

  {
    car: 'Highlander Hybrid',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.med,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Buick Enclave',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.med,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Mazda CX-7',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.med,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'BMW X5',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.med,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Honda Pilot AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.med,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Buick Enclave AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.med,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Mazda CX-7 AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.med,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.money
    }
  },  
  {
    car: 'BMW X5 AWD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.med,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },

  {
    car: 'Chevy Tahoe',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.big,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Audi A7',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.big,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Chevy Tahoe',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.big,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Cadallac Escalade',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.big,
      drive: types.drive.city,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Chevy Tahoe 4WD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.big,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Infiniti QX80 4WD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.big,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.gas,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Ford Expedition 4WD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.big,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.save
    }
  },
  {
    car: 'Caddalac Escalade 4WD',
    requirements: {
      size: types.size.big,
      drive: types.drive.mountain,
      mpg: types.mpg.performance,
      money: types.money.luxury
    }
  },  
];

const getElements = () => {
  const checkedValue = selector => (
  document.querySelector('input[name = "' + selector + '"]:checked').value
  );

  return {
    size: checkedValue('size'),
    drive: checkedValue('drive'),
    mpg: checkedValue('mpg'),
    money: checkedValue('money'),
    submit: document.getElementById("submit"),
    suggestion: document.getElementById("suggestion")
  };  
}

function submit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const {
    size,
    drive,
    mpg,
    money,
    suggestion
  } = getElements();

  const result = cars.find(({
    requirements
  }) => (
  requirements.size === size &&
  requirements.drive === drive &&
  requirements.mpg === mpg &&
  requirements.money === money
  ));

  suggestion.innerHTML = result.car;
}

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", submit);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to manage that. I try to explain one solution, but I cannot give you a complete script solution since I do not think that is the scope of StackOverflow.

The first thing, you can make, is to group your different questions in html tags. Mostly, a `div` tag is a good choice, e.g.:

```
<div id="question1">
  <p>What size do you need?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="compact">Compact<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="mid">Midsize<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="small">Small SUV<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="med">Medium SUV<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="big">Big SUV
</div>
```

Subsequently, use a class that hides the div's you do not need:

```
/* CSS */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="question2" class="hidden">...</div>
<div id="question3" class="hidden">...</div>
```

Instead of the form, you can replace the form with also with a `dig` tag and add to buttons to it. The first button (previous) is hidden, the other button (next) is visible.

For the current question to display, you use a simple counter:

```
// JS
var question = 1;
```

If your 'next' button has the id 'next', add your event handler for a click event:

```
// JS
var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
nextButton.onClick = function() {
  // Increment the current question
  question++;
  if (question > MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    // Hide the button
    nextButton.className += " hidden";
  }
  // Hide the last question
  document.getElementById('question' + (question - 1)).className += " hidden";
  // Show the current question
  document.getElementById('question' + question).className =
    document.getElementById('question' + question).className.replace("hidden", "");
}
```

And so on. I think you will figure out the rest by your own.

Remember, this is pure JS. You can also use some libraries that makes learning JS at the beginning much easier, e.g., jQuery.

For adding and removing classes from dom elements, you can also implement the functions described here: https://jaketrent.com/post/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/